# НЕ розмовний український відповідник до слова "ornate"

Tags: переклад, вживання-слів, from-english, значення-слів

Мені потрібний прикметник, який би описував бароковий стиль архітектури і всього решти барокового. Перекладаю англійське "[ornate](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/ornate)":

> 1. Elaborately or highly decorated.

В [укр-англ словнику Андрусишина і Крета](https://e2u.org.ua/s?w=ornate%20&dicts=all&highlight=on) знайшов слово, яке підходить якнайкраще, "поцяцькований", але воно виявилося розмовним, як і всі однокореннєві прикметники.

Йду за синонімічним рядом з [цього сайту](https://ukrainskamova.com/publ/slovnik_sinonimiv/c/cjackovanij/45-1-0-5843):

> Синонiмі до слова ЦЯЦЬКОВАНИЙ:обцяцькований, поцяцькований; (-
>   тканини) мережаний, мережчатий, узористий; (квітами) заквітчаний, ІД.
>   квітчастий; (різьбою) різьблений; (посуд) …

СУМ 70-80 каже, що слова "[цяцькований](http://sum.in.ua/s/obcjacjkovanyj)", "[обцяцькований](http://sum.in.ua/s/obcjacjkovanyj)", "[поцяцькований](http://sum.in.ua/s/pocjacjkovanyj)" - це **розмовні слова**. У пізнішому СУМ-20 до тих слів ще не дійшло, а значення цих слів таке:

> 2. у знач. прикм. Прикрашений оздобами, вкритий візерунками.

Тож до синонімічного ряду:

[Мережчатий](http://sum.in.ua/s/merezhchatyj) і мережаний - це:

> Оздоблений мережками. //  Схожий на мережку, мереживо.

[Заквітчаний](http://sum.in.ua/s/zakvitchanyj), квітчастий надто концентрується на квітах, хоч і має значення як прикметник до [ось такого](http://sum.in.ua/s/zakvitchuvaty) дієслова:

> Взагалі оздоблювати чим-небудь, надавати привабливого вигляду чомусь.

(Це поки що найближчий до оздоблення прикметник, але я не бачу його в архітектурному контексті, а ось поцяцькований звучить і щодо архітектури, будівель, які хтось надто інтенсивно оздобив, наприклад). Тобто, проблема в тому, що оздоблення може бути не пов’язане з квітами і кольорами.

[Різьблений](http://sum.in.ua/s/rizjblenyj) не каже про велику інтенсивність оздоблення, взагалі не підходить.

Узористий (взористий) і [взірчастий](http://sum.in.ua/s/vzirchastyj) (взорчастий, узорчастий) - це просто:

> Який має візерунки, прикрашений візерунками.

Це слово також не має у собі надміру або інтенсивності оздоблення.

Допоможіть, будь ласка, знайти слово, яке б позначало надмірне або інтенсивне оздоблення, але при цьому не було б розмовним.

Comment: гадаю, РОЗДЕКОРОВАНИЙ підійде

Comment: @ХристинаВороніна, коментарі не призначені для надання (напів-)відповідей. Мета коментарів — спонукати автора покращити/уточнити своє запитання. Якщо маєте відповідь, краще оформити її як відповідь.

Comment: А чим банальні варіанти з Google Translate не підходять: «оздоблений»/«прикрашений»/«нарядний»/«пишно оздоблений»/«пишно прикрашений»?

Comment: @Sasha як на мене, перші три можуть характеризувати будь-яку епоху, бо оздоблювали завжди, а ось останні два + просто слово "пишний" досить добре підходять (я просто чомусь навіть не подумав про цей корінь. (пишний). Будете писати відповідь чи мені самому?

Answer (score 1):

ВИТІЮВА́ТИЙ, а, е, книжн. Вигадливий, позбавлений простоти; надмірно вишуканий, пишномовний. Поважно, невеличкими купами походжали вони.., зупиняючись обдивитися то який-небудь будинок витіюватий, то церкву (Панас Мирний, III, 1954, 257).

[СУМ](http://sum.in.ua/s/vytijuvatyj)

ПИ́ШНИЙ, а, е.

//  Який відзначається високим ступенем вияву чого-небудь. 
//  З гарними упорядкованими будівлями (про населений пункт).
//  Великий, місткий, з архітектурними прикрасами, оздобленням (про будинок, палац, храм і т. ін.).

[СУМ](http://sum.in.ua/s/pyshnyj)

ХИМЕ́РНИЙ, а, е.

1. Який викликає подив, не схожий на когось звичайного або щось звичайне; незвичний, чудернацький. На самому вершечку його [косогору], ніби вінчаючи собою найвище місце, стояв двоповерховий химерної архітектури будинок (Василь Козаченко, Сальвія, 1959, 15)

[СУМ](http://sum.in.ua/s/khymernyj)

Comment: я вже проголосував за відповідь, а якщо ви додасте з посиланням на коментар Саші ще й «пишно оздоблений»/«пишно прикрашений» (це нормально, інформацію з чужих коментарів можна брати до своїх відповідей), то я ще й прийму її, бо тоді вона для мене буде цілісною і повною.